# Função Mail() do PHP desabilitada impacta no SMTP?

Tags: php, phpmailer, smtp, gmail

Estou enfrentando problemas com o PHPMailer, a versão da classe é a **5.1**, que está gerando o seguinte erro: `Could not instantiate mail function` erro esse que corresponde a um problema de instância.

Verificando as possíveis causas disso, analisei que a **Diretiva:** *disable_functions* está incluindo a função `mail()`.

Logo, ao utiliza-la tenho o seguinte erro:

> Warning: mail() has been disabled for security reasons

Diante de tudo isso, gostaria de saber se o erro gerado, *Could not instantiate mail function*, tem relação direta com a falta dessa função no `php.ini`.

**obs:** O servidor MX está configurado para o  **G Suite**, logo as configurações de SMTP são do google gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Removi isto e resolveu: `$mail->Mailer   = "SMTP";`

Comment: Queria apenas chamar a atenção do porque `->Mailer` disparou o `mail` ao invés de SMTP, se olhar na doc http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#property_Mailer notará que todos valores são lowercase, é provavel que o "valor" seja case-sensitive e porque a classe não entedeu o valor acabou assumindo o `mail`, note que pode usar `$mail->isSMTP();`. Só comentei para explicar, talvez seja algo para adicionar a resposta ;)